# va_start as array

Tags: c++

According to what I read about the `va_arg` macro, it that retrieves the next argument pointed by the argument list. Is there any way to choose the index of the argument I want to get, like an array index?

For example I need to do an operation where I need to call at least 3 times the `va_arg` macro but I want those 3 times to retrieve the same argument and not the next one on the list. One solution could be using a function and passing the argument, but I don't want that.

Also if there is no other macros able to do this, how can I reference to the start of the array arguments by a pointer? I know its not portable and not type safe, etc, etc. Just for the sake of learning.

Here is an example code of how i want to implement it:

```
bool SQLBase::BindQuery (char* query, int NumArgs, ...) 
{ 
    va_list argList; 
    va_start(argList, NumArgs); 
    SQLPrepare (hstmt, query, SQL_NTS); 
    for (int x = 0; x < NumArgs; x++) 
    { 
        SQLBindParameter (hstmt, (x+1), GetTypeParameter (va_arg(argList, SQLPOINTER*), SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, 10, 0, va_arg(argList, SQLPOINTER*), va_arg(argList, SQLLEN), &recvsize[x]);
    }
```

The va_arg is called 3 times for the SQLBindParameter function and i want the first 2 times to point to the same argument, not increasing the count member on the argument list.

Comment: Assign its return value to a variable.

Comment: What's to stop you using a variable? `SQLPOINTER* tmp = va_arg(argList, SQLPOINTER*);` That way you don't have to use var_arg twice for the same parameter. Another problem with your code is that C++ doesn't guarantee to evaluate arguments from left to right, so there's no guarantee which of your va_arg calls will happen first.

Comment: Nothing lol, i am just asking is there any macros that let me access the argument list as an array, its just for knowing. Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is. But there's nothing to stop you going through the arguments yourself and putting the values in an array.

Comment: If you expect us to provide non-portable hacks, you should also note what compiler and libc you are using.

Comment: Also, how is `GetTypeParameter()` declared? You seem to have an unclosed parenthesis there (ending args to `GetTypeParameter()`).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, calling va_arg multiple times in your function invocation is hairy, since you don't know in which order these calls happen. You need to do this beforehand, so your arguments are retrieved in the correct order.

Second, no: there is no array-style usage auf va_list. This is because va_list doesn't know a thing about the arguments on the stack; you are supplying the type in your va_arg calls, and va_arg can then increase the (internal/conceptual) pointer contained in the va_list because it knows the size of that argument. Getting to the third argument would require you to supply the types of the first two.

If all the arguments are the same size (like "void*") you can always just make a loop that calls va_arg the appropiate number of times. This is "kind of" portable if you can be reasonably sure that your arguments are in fact the same size. I'm not too confident that doing this would be the best course of action, though -- the need to do it might indicate that a different setup would be more appropiate, like passing an array in the first place instead of using a variable argument function.

You can also just take the address of a function argument and assume they are on the stack in some order. This is horribly unportable since you need to know about calling conventions which can vary between compilers, and may even change based on compilation options. I would definitely advise to NOT do something like this.